# Should I ask a new question, or edit the existing?

Tags: support, edits, asking-questions

The question "[What parameters can I pass to this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690388)" has, for now, [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690388/what-parameters-i-can-pass-to-this-function/7691401#7691401). I tried to implement and run the suggestion from that answer, but ran into problems doing so. I would like to get some help with or comments on my code.

Now, it maybe should be a comment to the answer, but my code sample will not fit.

Also, I cannot add it to the answer, because the code is not working and would render the answer useless.

Now, I could ask my problem as a new question, but in fact the problem is not mine: it is almost identical to the original question, I'm just more eager than OP... So yes, I am also curious about how to make the function work: How to build up or prepare the memory pointer which is supposed to be fead to the first parameter?

Is it permitted to edit the original question and append my try-outs? Maybe with a little explanation about my sudden involvement?

Comment: Is your question really "What parameters can I pass to this function," or is it something else?  If it's something else, ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I suppose I also have trouble feeding the function.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you don't comprehend an answer to the question of someone else, you can/should ask a new question. To be sure it isn't flagged as a duplicate question, explain your problem AND put a link to the original question in your new question. Write something like "I have tried doing as suggested here (and give the link) but I still have this and this problem".